# Get elements of an IEnumerator to a list

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# so go easy on me. Anyways, I made a list of numbers

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
```

and I want to make a list of each number and its count/frequency.

```
var grouped = numbers
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(i => new { Number = i.Key, Count = i.Count() });
```

In locals, I can see the group, which has an IEnumerator interface with all of the numbers and their count values [image of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufsz6.png). So is there a way to make a list with the numbers and their frequency/count?

Thank you.

Comment: Append that with `.ToList()`?

Comment: Alternatively, it's unclear why you want it in a list. There's nothing stopping you from looping over `grouped` as you have it now: `foreach(var item in grouped){ Console.WriteLine(item.Number); }`

Comment: Sounds like you want `ToDictionary` with the number as key and the frequency as value.

Comment: @bommelding To be able to write out each number and its frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is a sequence so it doesn't own a *count*. But `Enumerable.Count` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`

That is, you don't necessarily need to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` into a `List<T>`:

```
var grouped = numbers
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(i => new { Number = i.Key, Count = i.Count() });

var groupedCount = grouped.Count();

// You may iterate grouped
foreach(var value in grouped) 
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{value.Number} {value.Count}");
}
```

If you really need `List<T>` semantics, you just need to call `Enumerable.ToList`:

```
var grouped = numbers
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(i => new { Number = i.Key, Count = i.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

In the other hand, you may directly convert everything into a `string` as follows:

```
var groupText = string.Join("\n", numbers
                                 .GroupBy(i => i)
                                 .Select(i => $"Number: {i.Key} Count: {i.Count()}"))
```

Comment: aah, ok. Thank you for providing me with clarity. Works great!

Comment: @NikM No problem! I'm glad it solved your dilemma :D

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) with the number as key and the frequency as value:

```
var grouped = numbers
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(i => new { Number = i.Key, Count = i.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Number, x => x.Count);
```

Now you can easily print every number and its frequency by looping the dictionary.

In fact you don´t even *need* neither `ToDictionary` nor your `Select`, as the `IGrouping` returned from `GroupBy` also derives from `IEnumerable` which is why you can iterate over it.

```
foreach(var g in grouped = numbers.GroupBy(i => i))
{
    var number = g.Key;
    var freq = g.Count();
}
```

Comment: Personal preference, but I would find this clearer without the select between groupby and todictionary...

Answer (score 0):

To get a list, you just need to call `ToList()`, for example:

```
var grouped = numbers
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(i => new { Number = i.Key, Count = i.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

However, you really don't need to do that, you can simply loop over the enumerable as it stands:

```
foreach(var item in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Number} occurs {item.Count} times"); 
}
```